# Recursive delete TreeViewItems in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, recursion, treeview

I am parsing an XML file and displaying it as a TreeView. Then, I need to do a phrase search, deleting all branches that do not contain a mention
Now I have the following recursive function code, but it does not work correctly. I must say right away that there can be quite a lot of branches and I cannot know in advance the degree of nesting

```
void RecursiveSearch(TreeViewItem item)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem children in item.Items)
    {
        if (children.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            RecursiveSearch(children);
        }
        if (children.Header.ToString().Contains(searchTB.Text) == false)
        {
            item.Items.Remove(children);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And call this on Button Click:

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RecursiveSearch((TreeViewItem)treeView.Items[0]);
}
```

Could you suggest what is wrong with it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "but it does not work correctly". Seems like you are removing the treenode which not contains the search string. What should happen if the parent does not contain the string but the children does?

Comment: @Sebastian Siemens parent must stay. The thing is that the function must reach the moment when the child has no children, and if it contains a string, go above, leaving it. Etc.
And now it deletes everything, up to the first branch

Comment: You could check if the children to be removed has children. e.g. `If (children.Items.Count == 0)` Only if there are no children you remove that item from tree.

Comment: Should I add your code inside the string existence check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i read in your comments my suggestion would:

```
void RecursiveSearch(TreeViewItem item)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem children in item.Items)
    {
        if (children.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            RecursiveSearch(children);
        }
        if (children.Header.ToString().Contains(searchTB.Text) == false)
        {
            If (children.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                item.Items.Remove(children);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```